# Docker changes IPtables FORWARD policy to DROP

Tags: amazon-web-services, iptables, amazon-linux

I've got OpenVPN on Amazon Linux 2 EC2 instance and need to forward packets through it. It works until I start `docker` on the instance. Then the FORWARD policy turns to DROP and VPN stops working.

```
[root@ip-... ~]# iptables -L FORWARD
Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)                             <<< See it's ACCEPT
target     prot opt source               destination
```

Then I start docker and check again:

```
[root@ip-... ~]# systemctl start docker

[root@ip-... ~]# iptables -L
Chain FORWARD (policy DROP)                               <<<< Turned to DROP
target     prot opt source               destination         
DOCKER-USER  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
DOCKER-ISOLATION-STAGE-1  all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere            
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

I tried to set the policy in `/etc/sysconfig/iptables` but that doesn't help.

This seems specific to Amazon Linux 2, I don't seem to have this problem on Ubuntu.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's a known behaviour, documented here: [**Docker on a router**](https://docs.docker.com/network/iptables/#docker-on-a-router)

The solution is to add an `ACCEPT` rule into `DOCKER-USER` chain:

```
~ # iptables -I DOCKER-USER -j ACCEPT
```

To make this change permanent you can put it to `/etc/sysconfig/iptables`:

```
*filter
:DOCKER-USER - [0:0]
-A DOCKER-USER -j ACCEPT
COMMIT
```

This will pre-create the `ACCEPT` rule and when docker starts and changes the `FORWARD` policy to `DENY` the packet forwarding will still work.

Hope that helps :)

Comment: I am commenting here to add that I lost connectivity to my bridged VMs after installing Docker. Also, there is no /etc/sysconfig/iptables on Debian Buster. A package named *iptables-persistent* might address this, but I fixed this problem by adding `iptables -P FORWARD ACCEPT` to /etc/rc.local.

Comment: The same thing happens with ip6tables, but there is no DOCKER-USER chain in ip6tables. 